# how to control multiple chat activites in android?

Tags: android, asmack

Sorry for my long question, but I need to explain it.

I am developing android chat client using asmack API. I have created the connection and can have chat with a friend. Now I am changing it to GUI client and want to have this functionality that a user can chat with more than one friends. It means that if two chat activities are open one will be active and one will be in pause state. I need some idea how do I add this function that a user can have chat with multiple users at the same time. Do I need to implement some background service which will communicate with the paused activity or this can be achived by some other way?

If I need to implement the background service what could be the functionality of the service? Please guide me if im on a wrong track.

Comment: I did this before. It's far from simple explanation. You can store activity and use class extended dialog to display current chats. It similar with `Alt` + `Tab`.

Comment: @Yul Thank you for your msg. Do you have any kind of helping material regarding this feature? It would be really helpful if you provide some more detail or any helping tutorial. What do you mean by store activity? and why do i need to extend my class to Dialog? Actually I am not expert in android im learning it by myself.

Comment: Did you also have this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223492/cant-get-history-of-multiuserchat-room-when-connecting-to-more-then-1-room really stuck on this :(

Answer (score 1):

The whole chat system should be separated from UI. And UI should simply "bind" to the chat "stream" to send/receive data. This would let you to switch between chats and these "invisible" chats could still receive messages from your parties. Also you want your app to be able to receive messages even when app is "in background" so there's not really any other choice. Not to mention that approach would help you building i.e. UI for tablet with more than one visible chat.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I want to know that the chat System should be a Service or it can be a normal chat activity class? I dont think that it should be an activity class which extends an Activity but it should extend Service class which can run in background.

Comment: It have to be sevice otherwise your chat system will not work if user leave your activity

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a long running service. I actually extend the Application class which has a much shorter life-cycle than the Service class but because of limitations on bandwidth/connectivity/battery in the mobile environment I don't need it to maintain a persistent connection.

To get around this I utilize a Broadcast receiver and google GCM API to receive offline notifications.

Obviously you also have to implement your own internal Intent service to notify the activities when a chat has arrived.

Hope this helps